# Odoo 7 NameError: name 'amount_to_text' is not define

Tags: python, openerp-7

I'm using openERP 7, I want to print the amount of a invoice to text in  sale_order report, i found some questions about the same error and I followed the instructions but is not working (https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/conversion-of-amount-to-text-in-openerp-43765) I tested with this answer and with amount_to_text_es_MX .

First I changed the sale_order.py file, I imported amount_to_text

```
import time

from openerp.report import report_sxw
from tools.translate import _
from tools import amount_to_text
from addons.l10n_mx_invoice_amount_to_text import amount_to_text_es_MX

class order(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(order, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'show_discount':self._show_discount,
            'amount_to_text_es_MX': amount_to_text_es_MX,
        })
```

After in my report I wrote

`[[str(amount_to_text_es_MX(o.amount_total,"Pesos"))]]`

The log showed the following error

```
2015-01-15 18:19:00,914 22621 ERROR Gaby openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval 'str(amount_to_text_es_MX(o.amount_total,"Pesos"))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 285, in safe_eval
    return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'amount_to_text_es_MX' is not defined
```

I hope that someone can help me 
Thanks,
Gaby

Comment: Add the import of amount to text in the init file too. Restart and tell me if it works

Comment: I solved the problem :D . I added the import code in  openerp/addons/sale_order.py , the problem was that the installation added 2 directories of addons, I added the import code only to one directory, but to the  other not. And also I moved it the file amount_to_text.py to python2.7/dist-packages Thanks!!